# Configuring the dvips driver. Can I modify the config.ps file?

Tags: miktex, texmaker, dvips

I'm having some trouble with paper sizes when I use the sequence

Latex->dvips->ps2pdf

to compile my `.tex` file. I have figured out that the problem is with the dvips bit. I want a letter size document and it keeps turning it into an A4.

I'm using the MiKTeX 2.9 distribution on Windows 7 and the Texmaker editor. How do I change the dvips driver configuration and set the default paper size as letter? I have changed the `config.ps` file into a `.txt` file so I could look to what's inside of it and change what was necessary but at the beginning of the document there's a warning saying I cannot change that file... that I have to create a new file that will override the `config.ps`.

What should I do? What's the code to set the letter size as default and where should I put it?

Thank you very much.

The `.tex` I'm having problems with

```
\documentclass[letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage{pst-all}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage[]{geometry}

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

\psset{arrowscale=3.5}

\pspicture(30.9,23.3)(3.4,16)

\psgrid[griddots=10,gridlabels=10pt, subgriddiv=0, gridcolor=black](1,3)(0,2)(19.5,26.5)

\endpspicture

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Dvips  takes into account what is declared by you file or the class you use. This hasn't to be set in `config.ps`. Maybe try `MiKTeX Package Manager`, and change the paper size:

[image]

Comment: I did it. Did not work.

Comment: Could you post a minimal (non-)working example?

Comment: I have just put my .tex example on the question above. I have tried the options for the geometry package but it did not work as well. I was told this has nothing to do with the .tex file because the dvips gets its input from the .dvi file which has no paper size specification.

Answer (score 0):

1. The LaTeX file has correctly declared `letterpaper` (it's also the default for class `article`. This can be checked by `\showthe\paperwidth` and `\showthe\paperheight`, the result is:

   ```
   > 614.295pt.
   l.9 \showthe\paperwidth

   > 794.96999pt.
   l.10 \showthe\paperheight
   ```

   1in is 72.27pt or 72bp.
2. Package `geometry` informs the driver via `\special` of the paper size. Running `latex test` should produce the `.dvi` file. The papersize setting can be checked by `dvitype test.dvi |grep xxx`. If you do not have grep, search for the string `xxx` or `papersize` in the output of `dvitype`. Then you should find one line:

   ```
   326: xxx 'papersize=614.295pt,794.96999pt'
   ```
3. Now `dvips` generates the PostScript file (`dvips test`). Open the PostScript file with a text viewer or editor. Near at the top, the paper size can be found:

   ```
   %%BoundingBox: 0 0 612 792
   %%DocumentPaperSizes: Letter
   ```

   The unit in PostScript and PDF is `bp`, not `pt`.

   The paper size setting in the DVI file can be overwritten by option `-t ...` of `dvips`.
4. `ps2pdf test.ps` generates the PDF file. There the paper size can be extracted via `pdfinfo test.pdf`:

   ```
   Page size:      612 x 792 pts (letter)
   ```

   Again the unit is `bp`.

   Also Acrobat Reader shows the page size, when moving the mouse to the lower left corner.

   The paper size setting in the PostScript file can be overwritten by option `-sPAPERSIZE=...` for `ps2pdf`.

This should work as outlined. There is no need to meddle with configuration files.

Comment: I wrote a simple "Hello World" .tex file and then produced a .dvi file using Latex. I then used dvips to produce a .ps file which I opened with my Texmaker to found everything you said I would, that is the


%%BoundingBox: 0 0 612 792
%%DocumentPaperSizes: Letter

bit. You said the "The paper size setting in the DVI file can be overwritten by option -t ... of dvips." I did not understand this part. In which file should I write the -t piece of code?

Comment: @Gabu Why do you want to overwrite the paper size in `dvips`, if the PostScript file already has the correct paper size?

Comment: The pdf generated at the end of the sequence

Latex -> dvips -> ps2pdf

is always an A4 size. I don't know what is happening.

Comment: @Gabu If the PostScript file is correct and `pdfinfo` does not report letter but A4, then the problem is the conversion to PDF. Is it a standard Ghostscript installation? Which version? Does `ps2pdf -sPAPERSIZE=letter` help?

Comment: It is the Ghostscript 9.16. Where do I put this command line ps2pdf -sPAPERSIZE=letter? (I'm sorry. I'm not a computer sciences student. I'm just trying to get my reports and papers right.)

Answer (score 0):

put a copy of config.ps in the same location (dvips/config) in some local texmf-tree. Open this copy in some editor and then move

```
@ letter 8.5in 11in
@+ ! %%DocumentPaperSizes: Letter
@+ %%BeginPaperSize: Letter
@+ letter
@+ %%EndPaperSize
```

before

```
@ letterSize 8.5in 11in
@+ ! %%DocumentPaperSizes: Letter
```

Save the file (make sure that is still named config.ps), update the FNDB and try again.

(untested, also it is long ago that I had to adapt config.ps, so it could be that I didn't remember correctly that this is the source of the problem).